# Automatically add column to one table upon the entry of a record in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I am working on a database, one of whose tasks is to store currencies with the following details:

1. The currency code (primary key)
2. The currency name
3. The purchase rate
4. The sale rate
5. The current balance
6. The minimum balance

The dilemma I'm facing is that while I want to be able to add currencies in dynamic fashion, I also have a Balances Brought Down table in the same database which is supposed to enumerate and store the balances for each currency for each particular date, that is:

1. Date (Primary Key)
2. Currency1 BalanceBD
3. Currency2 BalanceBD and so forth

So my question is, more broadly, is it possible (or even accepted practice) to add a column in one table upon the insertion of a row in another? In this case, adding a Currency BalanceBD column in the Balance Brought Down table when I add a record (new currency) in the Currency table. I was thinking of using triggers to automate the process, but it doesn't seem like a clean solution (or even a clean implementation for the logic--though it's the best I could come up with).

Any solution or improvement of the implementation would help.

Comment: Seems like it would be better to just have currency_code column in your Balances table that links to the currency table, with a column called BalanceBD.  Rather than dealing with adding columns.  May have to address DATE being your primary key as well.

Comment: I think you're on to something. Let me play around with that and see how far it goes, thanks.